# Trying to calculate $\int e^{2x}\sin(3x)\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I calculate this integral?

$$ \int {\exp(2x)}{\sin(3x)}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried using integration by parts, but it doesn't lead me any improvement. So I made ​​an attempt through the replacement $$ \cos(3x) = t$$ and it becomes $$\frac{1}{-3}\int \exp\left(2\left(\dfrac{\arccos(t)}{3}\right)\right)\, \mathrm{d}t$$ but I still can not calculate the new integral. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**:

$$\int {\exp(2x)}{\sin(3x)}\, \mathrm{d}x = \int {\sin(3x)}\, \mathrm{d(\frac{\exp(2x)}{2}))}=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}{\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{1}{2}\int {\exp(2x)}\,  \mathrm{d}(\sin(3x))=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}{\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{3}{2}\int {\exp(2x)}{\cos(3x)}\mathrm{d}x=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}{\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{3}{2}\int {\cos(3x)}\mathrm{d(\frac{\exp(2x)}{2}))}=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}{\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{3}{4}{\cos(3x)}{\exp(2x)}+\frac{3}{4}\int {\exp(2x)}\mathrm{d({\cos(3x)})}=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}{\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{3}{4}{\cos(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{9}{4}\int {\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$ =>(1+\frac{9}{4})\int {\exp(2x)}{\sin(3x)}\, \mathrm{d}x= \frac{1}{2}{\sin(3x)}{\exp(2x)}-\frac{3}{4}{\cos(3x)}{\exp(2x)}+c$$

$$=\frac{1}{13}\exp(2x)(2\sin(3x)-3\cos(3x))+c$$

Comment: By $sen$, do you mean $\sin$?

Comment: Note that $e^{2x}\sin (3x)$ is the imaginary part of $e^{?}$.

Comment: @AhaanRungta Yep, sorry. I just edited.

Comment: Let $I$ be your integral. Integrate by parts twice. You'll wind up with an equation of the form $I=$ stuff $+cI$, where $c$ is a constant. Solve for $I$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use integration by parts or use the identity

$$ \sin  y = \frac{e^{iy} - e^{-iy} }{2i}  $$

Which makes the integral easier.

Comment: An alternative, as julien noticed: write $e^{(2+3i)x}=e^{2x}\cos(3x)+ie^{2x}\sin(3x)$, then integrate the LHS and you get two primitives in the RHS (taking real and imaginary parts). The imaginary part is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate by parts twice, either differentiating the exponential each time or differentiating the trig function each time.  You will be able to solve for the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\sin(3x)\, \mathrm{d}x=Ae^{2x}\sin(3x)+Be^{2x}\cos(3x)$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constant.